# Detect if python script is run from console or by crontab

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, cron

Imagine a script is running in these 2 sets of "conditions":

1. live action, set up in `sudo crontab`
2. debug, when I run it from console `./my-script.py`

What I'd like to achieve is an automatic detection of "debug mode", without me specifying an argument (e.g. `--debug`) for the script.

Is there a convention about how to do this? Is there a variable that can tell me who the script owner is? Whether script has a console at `stdout`?  Run a `ps | grep` to determine that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: similar to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086961/how-can-i-determine-if-a-python-script-is-executed-from-crontab)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since `sys.stdin` will be a [TTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTY) in debug mode, you can use the [os.isatty()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.isatty) function:

```
import sys, os
if os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno()):
    # Debug mode.
    pass
else:
    # Cron mode.
    pass
```

Answer (score 9):

You could add an environment variable to the crontab line and check, inside your python application, if the environment variable is set.

crontab's configuration file:

```
CRONTAB=true

# run five minutes after midnight, every day
5 0 * * *        /path/to/your/pythonscript
```

Python code:

```
import os

if os.getenv('CRONTAB') == 'true':
   # do your crontab things
else:
   # do your debug things
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a command line option that only cron will use.

Or a symlink to give the script a different name when called by cron. You can then use `sys.argv[0]`to distinguish between the two ways to call the script.

Comment: Although I think using `os.isatty()` to detect whether `sysout` is a terminal is a hack. the OP specifically said he did not want to to do it with a command line argument. In addition, it sounds like Python itself might be doing something like this in certain situations -- see the info for the **-i** interpreter command line option in the [1.1.3. Miscellaneous options](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html?highlight=command%20line%20option#miscellaneous-options) section of the online docs.