# Python3: command line interface and module import?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

So I have the following directory structure

- my_dir

  - my_mod

    - `__init__.py`
    - `myfile.py`

and in `myfile.py`

I have a nice command line interface via argparse.

But what if sometimes I want to import a function from this script and use it as if it were a module?

e.g. `from myfile import myfunc`

when I do this I get an error, mostly because I do some preprocess of the command line arguments which are all none in this case.

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213091/detect-if-python-script-is-run-from-console-or-by-crontab) S.O. post, I know how I can tell if python is called from the command line:

```
import sys, os
if os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno()):
    # do things
```

The inclusions of this line and corresponding replacement of my argument preprocessing does not solve this issue.

What should I do?

Comment: Your argparsing should only happen if the  `__name__` variable is equal to `"__main__"`. That's why many python scripts have an `if__name__=="__main__"` block calling their `main()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: @ElisByberi not a duplicate (as I do not ask what it does), but that may be the solution, so linking is useful

Comment: @khelwood ok, I shall try that out. thank you