# Log who ran a python script: cron or human?

Tags: python, linux, logging, cron

I created a python script which is usually run by a cron job, but the script can at times be run manually by a human. Is it possible to determine who ran the script and saved it in a log file?

I'm using python's `logging` library. It seems the `LogRecord` attributes `name` only shows the root as being the logger used to log the call.

```
log_format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a flag parameter to your script when calling the command in cron ? There's some answers [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213091/detect-if-python-script-is-run-from-console-or-by-crontab)

Comment: Nice, i'm going to have a look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

How about using command line options?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

When triggering the script from cron use a special argument that defaults to something else if not explicitly set.