# Is there a way to determine if a python script was started by Cron?

Tags: python, cron

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if a python script is executed from crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086961/how-can-i-determine-if-a-python-script-is-executed-from-crontab)

Is there a way to determine if a python script was started by cron or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not per se, but you could set an environment variable in the crontab and check it in the script.

```
* * * * * CRONRUN=y /srv/cron/foo.py
```

...

```
if 'CRONRUN' in os.environ:
   ...
```

Comment: Or pass an extra command line argument.

Comment: Nah, Ignacio's answer was what I was looking for. I didn't know you could set an environment var in front of something temporarily.

Comment: if you run `man 5 crontab`, for Ubuntu/Debian you can define global environmental value ( all crons ) as well.

Comment: check ( not run ) `man 5 crontab`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your script does, I can give a couple of suggestions.

If the script runs then terminates, have the script log its start and end time in a log file.

If the script is a process, or runs as a daemon, and you are using cron to start the script on a reboot (depending on the cron daemon you are using), you can use the program ps to view a snapshot of the current processes.